# How to print a list of all the rows which contain a certain value for a user?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MYSQL database which is set out like the following:
    user varchar(50).
    type1 int(50).
    type2 int(50).
I would like to create a php script where I could go do http://example.com/main.php/?user=example and the page would display a list which said the names of all the integers which equalled 1.

I can not determine the amount of rows as more rows will be added from another php file. 
All I can say is that row 1 will be called user and will be a varchar. The default value for every other row which will be and integer will be 0.

Thanks

Comment: create what? complete your question

Comment: You would like to create a *second half to the question* perhaps?

Comment: @Fluffeh You made my day man. Everyone around me were taken by surprise by my burst of laughter

Comment: Sorry acidently pressed enter before.

Comment: @BhuvanRikka its "asprin" not "aspirin"

Comment: Now i'm laughing! Sorry @asprin i didn't notice it.

Comment: Can someone please help.

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're to explain. Maybe that's why there ins't an answer yet

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear but i think what you are saying is you have a database table like this

```
  user  varchar2(50)
  type1 int(50)
  type2 int(50)
```

with some data like this (sorry it's a bit of a mickey mouse example :)

```
  user          type1       type2     type3
  -----------------------------------------
  mickey            0           1         0
  donald            1           1         0
  pluto             1           1         1
```

and if the browser calls the web page with a parameter of user=donald, you want to display

```
  type1
  type2
```

Is that right ?

Seems a bit strange but if this is the case, seems more likely you want a column that holds type so that you can just use a select statement against it

```
  user           type
  -----------------------
  mickey            type2
  donald            type1
  donald            type2
  pluto             type1
  pluto             type2
  pluto             type3
```

Then to get all the types that belong to a user, you would use an SQL select such as

```
  SELECT type from <table> where user='mickey';
```

which would return

```
  type
  --------
  type2
```

With a but of denormalisation, we would have a user table, a type table and a user_type table to save on space

```
  user

  id       name
  --------------------
  1        Mickey
  2        Donald
  3        Pluto

  type

  id       type
  --------------------
  1        type 1
  2        type 2
  3        type 3

  user_type

  user_id     type_id
  --------------------      
  1            2
  2            1
  2            2
  3            1
  3            2
  3            3
```

And then our select becomes

```
 SELECT type FROM user as u, user_type as ut, type as t 
 where u.id=ut.user_id
   and ut.type_id=t.id
   and u.name='Mickey'
```

This would then only store data where there is actually a value for that type/user combination.  You would then just need this select to be embedded in the php to do the select and retrieve the data you want.